# Bubble Sorting Confusion

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort, alphabetical

I'm trying to make a program that will read in a .txt file with words, and then put those words into another .txt file in alphabetical order. I've looked around for help and people keep saying that a bubble sort will do the trick, but none of them are very helpful or understandable and I don't know how to incorporate a bubble sort into my code, as follows:

```
ifstream normalfile;
ofstream alphabetized;
string word[250]
int i;
normalfile.open("/*filepath*/");
alphabetized.open("/*filepath*/");

if (!normalfile)
{
    cout << "Normal File Error" << endl;
    return 0;
}
if (!alphabetized)
{
    cout << "Alphabetized File Error" << endl;
    return 0;
}

for (i = 0; !normalfile.eof(); i++)
{
    normalfile >> word[i];
    cout << word[i] << " ";
}
```

Right now all it does is print out to the screen (and out to the text file when I finalize it) the original .txt file word for word in original order. How do I incorperate a bubble sort in this program to put in in alphabetical order?

Comment: There is no sorting anywhere in this code... are you just asking "how do you write a bubble sort"?

Comment: Yes, I'm basically asking how do I use a bubble sort in this code in particular.

Comment: @Herides You use a bubble sort in this code the same way you use a bubble sort in any code. There's nothing special about this code that requires some special way of using a bubble sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use bubble sort you should add this after your code:

```
int j, k;
string temp;

for(j = 0; j < i; ++j) /*since the last for i stores the amount of 
                        words you want to sort, so this for gets repeat i times */
    for( k = 0; k < i - j; ++k){ /*here you go trought the array first 
                                 until words[i - 1], second until words[i - 2] and so on..., 
                                 this because at the end of each cicle the last element 
                                 is garantized to be already in order*/
        if(words[k] > words[k + 1]){/*if the actual element words[k] is greather 
                                      than words[k + 1] swap their values*/
            temp = words[k];
            words[k] = words[k + 1];
            words[k + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

All is left is to put all the words in alphabetized;

```
for(j = 0; j < i; ++j){
    alphabetized << word[j];
}
```

That´s it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked exactly how I needed it to, and I have a better understanding. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the string from normalfile in 'word'.
After this you can try using sort function as sort(word.begin(),word.end()).Don't forget to include algorithm header. Now, since your word is sorted you can put its text in alphabetized file.
Hope it helps.

Comment: std::sort is not a bubble sort.